The natural map from compact vertical cohomology to de Rham cohomology is not injective
Let $\pi:E\to M$ be an oriented vector bundle. In Bott-Tu's book Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology, the compact vertical cohomology $H^*_{cv}(E)$ is defined by using differential forms $\omega$ on $E$ such that $\pi^{-1}(K)\cap \textrm{supp}(\omega)$ is compact for every compact subset $K\subset M$. There is a natural map $H^*_{cv}(E)\to H^*(E)$ induced by inclusion.
Let $\Phi\in H^*_{cv}(E)$ be the Thom class and $e\in H^*(M)$ be the Euler class of $\pi$. Then an exercise in the book asks to show that $\Phi=\pi^* e$ in $H^*(E)$ but not in $H^*_{cv}(E)$. The first assertion is clear: it is known that $s^*\Phi=e$ where $s$ is the zero section, so $\Phi=\pi^*s^*\Phi=\pi^*e$ in $H^*(E)$. But how can we show the second assertion? There is a global formula of $\Phi$ given in section 12: $\Phi=d\rho(r)\cdot \psi -\rho(r)\pi^*e$. I think I should show that $\Phi-\pi^*e=d\rho(r)\cdot \psi-(\rho (r) +1)\pi^*e$ cannot be the differential of a form with compact vertical supports, but I can't see why. Any hints?
P.S. As pointed out in the comment, $\pi^* e $ does not have vertically compact support. Is the natural map $H^*_{cv}(E)\to H^*(E)$ surjective in general?

The pullback of a non-zero form on $M$ never belongs to $\Omega^*{cv}(E)$. So how do you even make sense of $\pi^e$ as an element of $H^{cv}(E)$?

@DerivedCats You're right. Do you think that the exercise do not make sense?

The map $\iota: H^*_{cv}(E) \rightarrow H^*(E)$ induced by inclusion of forms is neither injective nor surjective in general. You can consider these two examples.

Let $\pi: E \rightarrow S^1$ be the usual Möbius bundle over the circle, you have $H^*_{cv}(E) = H^*_c(E) = 0$ because $S^1$ is compact and the compact cohomology of the open Möbius band vanishes. On the other hand $H^*(E) = H^*(S^1) \neq 0$, so $\iota$ is not surjective in such a case.

Let $\pi: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the projection on the first coordinate, seen as a rank 1 vector bundle. Using Poincaré Lemma for Compact Vertical Cohomology you have $H^1_{cv}(\mathbb{R}^2) = H^0(\mathbb{R}) = \mathbb{R}$, but $H^1(\mathbb{R}) = 0$. Thus $\iota$ is not injective.


I think the only "nice map" between compact vertical and de Rham cohomology is given by integration along the fiber composed with the pullback of the projection, that is in fact an isomorphism. Maybe there are other connections between the two if you add some more hypotheses. For instance you can consider M to be compact (and orientable if you want your cohomology to have coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$) so that $H^*_{cv}(E) = H^*_c(E)$ and you have the isomorphism $(H^{n - q}_c(E))^* \cong H^q(E)$ given by Poincaré Duality, with $n = \mathrm{dim}E$. I don't know if this is of any importance or if there are deeper connections between these two cohomologies. However, I hope I was helpful.
